# How to use environmental variables in the gradle plugins block?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using gradle 6.7 and have the following `build.gradle` script and it works totally fine:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.4.31"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization" version "1.4.31"
    id "application"
}

// Other things
```

But when I try to replace the hardcoded versions with `System.env.KOTLIN_VERSION` or `"${System.env.KOTLIN_VERSION}"` I start getting compilation errors: `build file 'build.gradle': 2: argument list must be exactly 1 literal String or String with property replacement`. The file itself looks as follows:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version System.env.KOTLIN_VERSION
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization" version System.env.KOTLIN_VERSION
    id "application"
}

// Other things
```

I know that the usual approach is to use `gradle.properties` file and specify version there. However this `KOTLIN_VERSION` env variable is set at the Dockerfile and I must use it. Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be: you can't.

The version should be a constant, and evaluating the environment variable isn't.

You may try to use something as in https://docs.gradle.org/5.6/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management

So, define a version in `gradle.properties`, and use it when defining a plugin version:

```kotlin
val helloPluginVersion: String by settings
pluginManagement {
  plugins {
    id("org.gradle.sample.hello") version "${helloPluginVersion}"
  }
}
```

Later on, you may just use the plugin in a `build.gradle.kts` without specifying the version (it was already defined in `settings.gradle.kts`)

so:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.gradle.sample.hello")
}
```